# Странности с расчётом ширины изображения во flex-контейнере

Tags: html, css, flexbox

В приведённом ниже примере Firefox ужимает картинку до её ширины, а Chrome не ужимает. Вопрос — почему? Чем обусловлена разница — багами какого-то из браузеров, вольностями в спецификации или моим непониманием какого-то нюанса?

```css
body { margin: 0; }

main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fdd;
}

img {
  flex-shrink: 999999; /* AAAAAAAAAAAA */
}

div {
  width: 99.999%;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z28RW.jpg" alt="" />
    <div>Что-нибудь очень длинное тут</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Вероятный ответ на ваш вопрос на английском stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521054/flex-in-firefox-shrinks-images-automatically-but-not-in-chrome

Comment: @ПавелЕриковstandwithRussia возможно, однако странно то, что если походить по ссылкам и добраться до баг-трекера Firefox, то там написано, что баги исправлены года три назад, но различие в поведении почему-то наблюдается и сейчас